# Converting any file to .xlsx leads error in opening it

Tags: c#, ms-office

I am saving as any file to .xlsx format. If the original file is not with .xlsx extension, it is throwing exception while trying to open it. The exception message is :-

> Excel cannot open the file 'abc.xlsx because the file format or file
>   extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted
>   and that the file extenstion matches the format of the file.

Whereas if conversion is in .xls format, I can open the converted file with warning message.

> The file you are trying to open, abc.xls, is in a different format
>   than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not
>   corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you
>   want to open the file now?

I need to convert file to .xlsx format by C# code regardless its extenstion and open it by Excel 2010.

Comment: Converting isn't the same as renaming the file -  I suspect you are renaming the file. Lets say I hand you a shovel, but tell you its an apple. Would you still eat it?

Answer (score 2):

Thats not how file-types work!

You can not simply rename a file and it gets converted to a different type.

Renaming `*.xls` to `*.xlsx` works, because both are Excel files which can be opened by MS Excel, but for all other types (except some other which Excel can handle, like e.g. `*.csv`) you need to read the file and "manually" convert them.

To write `*.xlsx` using C# you can use e.g. [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)).

Answer (score 0):

You need a library that convert the files for you.

I see that you need to open files from Office 2003, so you need to use something like **NPOI**

Unfortunately, even if **EPPLUS** is a great library for Office's files, it only support the OXML Documents like  `.xlsx` or `.docx` but not the `.xls`.

**NPOI** is a free opensource library to work with Office 2003->2010/3 files.

[Here is the link](http://npoi.codeplex.com/)